# Manufacturing variable names

Tags: javascript, extjs

I always come across situations in programming where I want to have a bunch of variables defined in a loop (e.g., soldierA, soldierB, soldierC,...) and assign them to certain objects.

```
someClassA = Ext.extend(someClassB) {
    initComponent {
        this.weekdays = [ 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 
                          'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday' 
                        ];
        for(var i = 0; i<7; i++) {
            var dummy = "this.vacation" +this.weekdays[i]; 
            dummy = 1;
        };
        console.log("I desire the following to be a 1: " +this.vacationMonday);
    }
}
```

Console lists an undefined elements.

What is the recommended course of action?

Comment: I tried to unbork it with '' tags but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the bracket notation to set dynamic variable names. Also note you have to assign directly, not the way you have it listed.

```
this["vacation" + this.weekdays[i]] = 1;
```

Comment: Corrected variable assignment.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest doing it a different way. You're trying to twist your code to work a certain way rather than structuring it naturally. I would suggest doing it like this:

```
someClassA = Ext.extend(someClassB) {
    initComponent {
        this.weekdays = [ 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 
                          'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday' 
                        ];
        this.vacations = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < weekdays.length; i++) {
            vacations[this.weekdays[i]] = 1;
        };
        console.log("I desire the following to be a 1: " +this.vacations['Monday']);
    }
}
```

It uses a `vacations` object to index the days by name instead of a bunch of unrelated variables.

Also, when you write `var dummy = "this.vacation" +this.weekdays[i]; dummy = i`, you're not doing what you think. I'll break it down here:

`var dummy =`: This declares a variable named "dummy" and assigns it the object after the equals sign.

`"this.vacation"`: This is a string containing the letters <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>. It's just those letters — it's not code, and it definitely doesn't access `this.vacation`.

`+this.weekdays[i];`: This appends the value of `this.weekdays[i]` to the string we just created. Altogether, we now have a string like "this.vacationMonday". Again, this is just a series of letters — it's not code.

`dummy = 1;`: This throws away the string we created and assigns the number 1 to `dummy`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and your recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

with `var dummy = "this.vacation" +this.weekdays[i];` you are actually just concatenating strings, what you want it to access the objects property and add dynamic properties to it and the only way to do this is like Matt King said by bracked notation.

This works because object properties in Javascript can be accessed with dot notation or like classic hash maps with bracket notation. Try the following code for example.

```
var myObj = {
    property1: 'One',
    property2: 'Two',
    property3: 'Three'
}

document.write(myObj.property1);
document.write(myObj['property2']);
document.write(myObj['property' + 3]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gxy53/

Comment: This is a good explanation of why Matt's suggestion works. Thanks.